# wrapping struct hierarchy into C++ classes

Tags: c++, c

How can this hierarchy be wrapped by C++ classes that contain member functions which call their C equivalents?

C often uses a significant number of hacks to obtain an inheritance hierarchy. One of which, is the `container_of` macro that is used heavily within the linux kernel. I'm working with an existing C library written in such a style, and I would like to adapt the struct hierarchy into one wrapped by C++. For purposes of illustration, I'll use the following struct hierarchy.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

extern "C" {
    struct a;

    typedef void (*callback_t)(struct a *self);

    struct a {
        callback_t cb;
    };

    struct b {
        struct a a;
        const char * name;
    };

    void handle_event(struct a *self) {
        self->cb(self);
    };

    void process_event(struct a * a) {
        handle_event(a);
    }

    void some_a_operation(struct a * self) {
        printf("some operation called on a @ %p\n", self);
    }

    void some_b_operation(struct b * self) {
        printf("some operation called on a @ %p\n", self);
    }

    void c_callback_handler(struct a * a)
    {
        struct b * b = container_of(a, struct b, a);
        printf("%s\n", b->name);
    }
};
```

Given no changes to the above code, I can see the following means.

## Delegation with wrappers

This overcomes the prior examples issues of `struct a` duplication at the cost of significant complexity.

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        A_Wrap = new A_wrapper {{A::Cb}, this};
        A_Obj = &A_Wrap->a_member;
    }
    virtual ~A() {
        delete A_Wrap;
    }
    void OperationA() {
        some_a_operation(A_Obj);
    }
    virtual void InstanceCb() {};
    // member functions access struct a via A_Obj
protected:
    struct A_wrapper {
        a a_member;
        A * A_member;
    };
    A_wrapper* A_Wrap;
    a * A_Obj;
private:
    static void Cb(a * self) {
        A_wrapper * a_wrapper = container_of(self, A_wrapper, a_member);
        a_wrapper->A_member->InstanceCb();
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B() {
        delete A_Wrap;
        B_Wrap = new B_wrapper {{&B::Cb}, this};
        A_Obj = &B_Wrap->b_member.a;
        B_Obj = &B_Wrap->b_member;
    }
    virtual ~B() {
        A_Wrap = nullptr;
        delete B_Wrap;
    }
    void OperationB() {
        some_b_operation(B_Obj);
    }
    virtual void InstanceCb() {
        std::cout << "B class" << std::endl;
    };
    // member functions access struct a via A_Obj
protected:
    struct B_wrapper {
        b b_member;
        B * B_member;
    };
    B_wrapper * B_Wrap;
    b * B_Obj;
private:
    static void Cb(a * self) {
        b * b_contained = container_of(self, b, a);
        B_wrapper * b_wrapper = container_of(b_contained, B_wrapper, b_member);
        b_wrapper->B_member->InstanceCb();
    }
};
```

## Usage Examples

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // C usage
    const char * b_name = "b struct";
    struct b b_cexample = {
            {c_callback_handler}, b_name
    };

    process_event(&b_cexample.a);
    some_a_operation(&b_cexample.a);
    some_b_operation(&b_cexample);


    // C++ usage example
    B b_cppexample;
    b_cppexample.InstanceCb();
    b_cppexample.OperationA();
    b_cppexample.OperationB();
}
```

Comment: do i understand correctly that you already have two working solutions and you want some input on which one would be better? In that case your question may be better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, while here you may get "too broad" or otherwise motivated down/close votes

Comment: You should use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for owning pointers.

Comment: Callbacks can be easily stored in a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and combine well with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to capture any relevant variable or object.

Comment: Although codereview is possibly a better area for this, my main question is there a better way to accomplish this. I'm cool if this is closed though, and I'll move it to codereview.

Comment: @backscattered It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. In the `c` version, I don't see where `b` comes into play.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I added some example operations for b. This is fairly standard method signatures in C libraries where the main struct that is central to a function is supplied as pointer within the first argument.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I can't see the use of a unique_ptr for the _Obj members as they may be deleted by subclasses. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @backscattered Right, now that I look more closely, `std::unique_ptr` is not applicable. Though I think that's because the ownership of `A_Obj` is illdefined. If you make a `B`, that instance's `~A` will try to delete `A_Obj` which I can't tell if it's deletable or not. And it's still not clear to me what `b` does in the first example. I'm not very familiar with `c`, so maybe is should be obvious, but perhaps a [MCVE] would be in order. Are you sure [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I updated the question to provide a full usage example. I hope this helps. You can compile it by concatenating all the code blocks together into a file.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the ownership of A is indeed ill-defined as it's a hack to attempt to mimic a contained struct.

Comment: @backscattered Is the problem that, in the case of a `B` you do not want `A` to have it's own `a` but rather to use `B::b`'s `a` instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes. That's definitely the problem with this implementation. Perhaps there's a better way of doing this.